# How to apply on click action on images in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpmawvy0/embedded/result/) which I have replicated by seeing the screenshot below:

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate everything in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpmawvy0/embedded/result/) from the design.

The snippets of CSS codes which I have used in order to align images in a straight line are:

```
 .product-contents   
 {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 padding: 1rem;
 }
```

**Problem Statement:**

In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpmawvy0/embedded/result/), now if I click on **any square images from the screenshot (Franchise Hub,Business Analytics, Tech Support, etc)** apart from the **Cloud Based & Mobile Image** then A **TV screen image(means a different image)** should appear as present in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvn3wq7w/7/embedded/result/).

And if I click on **Cloud Based and Mobile** image then a phone image should appear **(as shown in the current screenshot above)**

I am not sure how to apply that logic. I am pretty sure I need to use Javascript but I am not sure how to use that.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service.  You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I showed my effort in replicating the design. I just not able to apply the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Give your images unique id and hide all but one default details image. Then you attach event handler to each div that toggles image visible attribute based on id.

```
$('.sections').on('click', function(e) {
     val section = e.target.id;
     $('.sections').hide(); // hide all sections
     $('#' + section).show(); // display only clicked one
 });
```

Comment: In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpmawvy0/), I have given an images a unique id with the image id with the image name. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick glance of what you can do. Set `event listener` that will listen for `click` on the mentioned images and then, inside of the passed callback function, change the `css` properties of another element using `element.style.cssProperty` such as `display` to change it from `none` to `block`.

```js
const cbBtn = document.querySelector('div#cloud');
const container = document.querySelector('div.container');

cbBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  container.style.display = 'block';

  cbBtn.className = 'active';
});
```

```css
div#cloud {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
div#cloud:hover {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud">
  Cloud Based
</div>

<div class="container">
  CONTAINER CONTENT
</div>
```