# How to change the content with click of an image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLs3Lpef/2/embedded/result/) in which I want to apply some logic in it.

On clicking of **Franchise Hub** image, I want the desktop screen and the text next to it should appear **with the phone screen below and the content next to it getting hidden**.

Whereas on clicking of **Cloud Based and Mobile**, I want the mobile screen and the text next to it should appear **with the tv screen and the content next to it getting hidden**.

[image]

**Javascript:**

The Javascript code which I have tried in order to achieve the above logic is:

```
const cbBtn = document.querySelector('img#franchise-hub');

const cloudbasedtextipad = document.querySelector('div.cloudbasedtextipad');

cbBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
cloudbasedtextipad.style.display = 'block';
cbBtn.className = 'active';
});
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the Javascript code above so that on clicking different images, different contents should appear.

```js
const cbBtn = document.querySelector('img#franchise-hub');

const cloudbasedtextipad = document.querySelector('div.cloudbasedtextipad');

cbBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  cloudbasedtextipad.style.display = 'block';

  cbBtn.className = 'active';
});
```

```css
.product-contents {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.product-contents .product {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.product-contents .product #franchise-hub {
  margin-bottom: 22%;
}

.product-contents .product #cloud-based-mobile {
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}

.product-contents .product #business-analytics {
  margin-bottom: 28%;
}

.product-contents .product #tech-support {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #order-management {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #employee-management {
  margin-bottom: 18%;
}

.product-contents .product #white-label {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}

.product-contents .product #brand-control {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.product-contents .product #lead-tracking {
  margin-bottom: 28%;
}

.product-contents .product #custom-invoicing {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #goal-setting {
  margin-bottom: 26%;
}

.product-contents .product #customization-tools {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #royalty-calculator {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #email-marketing {
  margin-bottom: 24%;
}

.ipads {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tvs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.cloud-based-text {
  width: 50%;
}

.franchise-hub-text {
  width: 50%;
}

div.cloudbasedtextipad {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

div.franchisehubtv {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div class="product-contents">
  <div class="product">
    <img id="franchise-hub" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Franchise-Hub.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
    <p style=" font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">Franchise Hub</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product" style="background-color:green;border:0;">
    <img id="cloud-based-mobile" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cloud-white.png" alt="" width="70" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8042" />
    <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2;
         color: white;">Cloud Based & Mobile</p>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="cloudbasedtextipad">
  <div class="cloud-based-text">
    <p style="font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;color:#929397">Software that works the way you do</p>
    <p style="padding: 20px 11px;
    width: 90%;
    color:#3b3b3d;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 1.625;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;">We’re cloud-based and mobile-first, which means you can access everything you need, no matter where you are. The app lets you run your business without compromising any features or power, so employees are able to check in from worksites and stay up
      to date.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ipads">
    <div class="ipad">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ipad-Screen-4-153x300.png" alt="" width="153" height="300" class="size-medium wp-image-8091">
    </div>

    <div class="ipad">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ipad-Screen-4-153x300.png" alt="" width="153" height="300" class="size-medium wp-image-8091">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="franchisehubtv">
  <div class="franchise-hub-text">
    <p style="font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;color:#929397">Software that works the way you do</p>
    <p style="padding: 20px 11px;
    width: 90%;
    color:#3b3b3d;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 1.625;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;">We’re cloud-based and mobile-first, which means you can access everything you need, no matter where you are. The app lets you run your business without compromising any features or power, so employees are able to check in from worksites and stay up
      to date.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tvs">
    <div class="tv">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081">
    </div>
    <div class="tv">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Reposting the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50556345/how-to-apply-on-click-action-on-images-in-javascript-jquery/50556497#50556497), with a partial answer (my) from yesterday will not get you very far. Please consider doing your own research.

Comment: @MatusDubrava Hi Matus, I do agree, I used your answer. This time, I have broken into components and I have tried to fit your logic in my answer. I am not sure how to go ahead after that as I am not good with scripting.

Comment: Why didn't you mark your last question correct if you are using his solution?

Comment: @user5447339 What are you tring to do set a different css class name or change the src of an image?   Read up on setAttribute .

Comment: Please, feel free to use my answer as you please, that is not the point. But your question is too broad and you will hardly be able to find an answer for it here. I just suggest that you should learn at least some basics of JS and DOM handling so that you have enough knowledge to ask a specific question that will lead to that solution.

Comment: Use jQuery, and need to put some logic to just display 1 at a 
 time. https://jsfiddle.net/1ctdhcvj/

Comment: @Matus Dubrava  this isnt to broad ...just no feedback from OP.  Im out.

Comment: send your html code

Comment: it's so simple but i need your html code

Comment: Here is the [HTML code](https://jsfiddle.net/1ctdhcvj/).

Comment: @MatusDubrava Yes, I will definitely try learning basics of JS and DOM handling so that I have enough knowledge before asking any question.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh In the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ctdhcvj/embedded/result/), when I click on Franchise Hub, it works perfectly fine but when I click on `cloud based and mobile` both the contents seem to appear. Is there any we can hide the desktop one ?

Comment: ad an id to the image you want to change since their isnt one on the fiddle and change the src when clicked..document.getElementById('New ID for image to change').src = "New Src"

Comment: @user5447339 , yes please check the answer. It's implemented using Jquery. You can do it the same way using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selection Colour Toggle Implemented as well.

```js
$("#mobile").click(function() {
  if ($('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');
    $('#mobile').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
    $('#desktop').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
  } else {
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'flex');
    $('#mobile').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#desktop').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');

  }

});

$("#desktop").click(function() {

  if ($('.franchisehubtv').css('display') == "flex") {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'none');
    $('#desktop').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
    $('#mobile').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
  } else {
    $('.franchisehubtv').css('display', 'flex');
    $('.cloudbasedtextipad').css('display', 'none');
    $('#desktop').css('background-color', 'green');
    $('#mobile').css('background-color', 'lightgray');
  }
});
```

```css
.product-contents {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.product-contents .product {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.product-contents .product #franchise-hub {
  margin-bottom: 22%;
}

.product-contents .product #cloud-based-mobile {
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}

.product-contents .product #business-analytics {
  margin-bottom: 28%;
}

.product-contents .product #tech-support {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #order-management {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #employee-management {
  margin-bottom: 18%;
}

.product-contents .product #white-label {
  margin-bottom: 15%;
}

.product-contents .product #brand-control {
  margin-bottom: 20%;
}

.product-contents .product #lead-tracking {
  margin-bottom: 28%;
}

.product-contents .product #custom-invoicing {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #goal-setting {
  margin-bottom: 26%;
}

.product-contents .product #customization-tools {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #royalty-calculator {
  margin-bottom: 27%;
}

.product-contents .product #email-marketing {
  margin-bottom: 24%;
}

.ipads {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tvs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.cloud-based-text {
  width: 50%;
}

.franchise-hub-text {
  width: 50%;
}

div.cloudbasedtextipad {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

div.franchisehubtv {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-contents">
  <div class="product" id="mobile">
    <img id="franchise-hub" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Franchise-Hub.png" alt="" width="59" height="59" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-7942">
    <p style=" font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    margin-left: 7%;
    margin-right: 7%;
    line-height: 1.2;
    color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">Franchise Hub</p>
  </div>

  <div class="product" id="desktop" style="background-color:green">
    <img id="cloud-based-mobile" src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/cloud-white.png" alt="" width="70" height="50" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8042" />
    <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2;
         ">Cloud Based & Mobile</p>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="cloudbasedtextipad" style="display:none;">
  <div class="cloud-based-text">
    <p style="font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;color:#929397">Software that works the way you do</p>
    <p style="padding: 20px 11px;
    width: 90%;
    color:#3b3b3d;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 1.625;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;">We’re cloud-based and mobile-first, which means you can access everything you need, no matter where you are. The app lets you run your business without compromising any features or power, so employees are able to check in from worksites and stay up
      to date.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="ipads">
    <div class="ipad">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ipad-Screen-4-153x300.png" alt="" width="153" height="300" class="size-medium wp-image-8091">
    </div>

    <div class="ipad">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Ipad-Screen-4-153x300.png" alt="" width="153" height="300" class="size-medium wp-image-8091">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="franchisehubtv" style="display:flex;">
  <div class="franchise-hub-text">
    <p style="font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;color:#929397">Software that works the way you do</p>
    <p style="padding: 20px 11px;
    width: 90%;
    color:#3b3b3d;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    line-height: 1.625;
    font-family: 'Roboto'; font-weight: normal;">We’re cloud-based and mobile-first, which means you can access everything you need, no matter where you are. The app lets you run your business without compromising any features or power, so employees are able to check in from worksites and stay up
      to date.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="tvs">
    <div class="tv">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081">
    </div>
    <div class="tv">
      <img src="https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tv-Screen-2.png" alt="" width="177" height="129" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-8081">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't know, that's fine. Let me know if that's what you're looking for. But this isn't an efficient logic when you have multiple entries. i.e multiple blocks.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for.

Comment: I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9m9o01ms/1/embedded/result/) for your answer. I am wondering if the page load, what changes I need to do in the fiddle so that by default, `cloud based and mobile section` is clicked already.

Comment: Thank you, and the default is set to `Cloud Based and Mobile` section, please check the updated answer :)

Answer (score -1):

I implement the first case only.
You have to learn how to implement the second one.
First, the CSS for div.cloudbasedtextipad changed to

```
div.cloudbasedtextipad
{   
display: none;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-right: 15%;
align-items: center;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
padding: 2%;
margin-bottom: 5%;
}
```

And the javascript changed as the following:

```
    const cbBtn = document.querySelector('img#franchise-hub');

    const cloudbasedtextipad = document.querySelector('div.cloudbasedtextipad');

    cbBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
        cloudbasedtextipad.style.display = 'flex';
    });
```

Comment: I implemented your code in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ctdhcvj/4/embedded/result/) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have to change the setting in fiddle, in the javascript drop down box, please set load type to "onDomReady".

Comment: This doesn't do what he asked at all...All your doing is swapping display not changing the image